# A phrase for "using a word repeatedly"

Tags: phrase-request, idioms, idiom-request

We all have some phrases which we repeat too much in our conversations. What do we call it when someone uses a word or a sentence again and again?

Answer (score 3):

We call it a "**Pet phrase**".

> A pet phrase is a phrase that an individual uses repetitively.

As an example:

> Whenever his conscience pricked him too keenly he would endeavor to
>   hearten himself with his **pet phrase**, 'All in a lifetime.' Thinking
>   over things quite alone in his easy-chair, he would sometimes rise up
>   with these words on his lips, and smile sheepishly as he did so.
>   Conscience was not by any means dead in him.

*(Theodore Dreiser, Jennie Gerhardt, 1911)*

Comment: If someone uses the same word of phrase frequently, we can also say that the use it habitually.